# bash directory name with a space in CDPATH

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to set a shortcut so that I don't have to type a really long directory name so often. In `~/.bash_profile`, I am doing something similar to:

```
export CDPATH=".:~:/This/Is/A/Really/Long/Path/That/Ends/With/My Name"
```

How do I escape/preserve the space in a directory name when trying to set this variable?

I've tried various solutions (using single quote vs double quote, escaping with a backslash (I even tried `'My\\\ Name'`), no quotes at all, and combinations of those options).

Gracias.

Comment: Did you try `export CDPATH=".:~:'/This/Is/A/Really/Long/Path/That/Ends/With/My Name'"`?

Comment: Have you tried if it works with directory without space? Maybe you should install bash-completion. Check out the end of my response (last  edit).

Comment: Also when you are trying check if $CDPATH is properly updated in your bash with `echo $CDPATH`. Don't forget to restart the console or directly `source ~/.bash_profile`. And try if it works with directory without space. Maybe there is something wrong with other settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export CDPATH=".:~:/This/Is/A/Really/Long/Path/That/Ends/With/My Name"
```

should be fine

I've tried

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir "aaa bbb"
mkdir "aaa bbb/a" "aaa bbb/b"
export CDPATH="/tmp/aaa bbb"
```

and

```
cd a
```

works just fine

Also if you want to change directory faster you can create an alias

```
alias longpath="cd '/This/Is/A/Really/Long/Path/That/Ends/With/My Name'"
```

but it will not solve the problem of copying to that directory

```
cp longpath
```

won't work.

Maybe it is not working properly and you should install and enable bash-completion — it defines a _cd function and sets it as the completer for the cd command, which overrides the default completion and includes $CDPATH.

Comment: I swear I had tried that. I'll try again. I am on OS X Mavericks. Are you using Linux? Does that make a difference?

Comment: (In the mean time, I think the "alias longpath" suggestion would work nicely.)

Comment: Yes I'm using linux. I'm not sure if it makes the difference I think it shouldn't.